# WinEdt over MiKTeX is not giving a PDF file. Can't reinstall MiKTeX

Tags: errors

I get this error from WinEdt (set to output to Sumatra):

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "Math490_hw3_S20"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\CarolM\Dropbox\MC_Classes\SPRING 2020\MATH 490 - CPX VAR\HOMEWORK\HW3

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: Math490_hw3_S20.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Math490_hw3_S20.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Math490_hw3_S20.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Math490_hw3_S20.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "Math490_hw3_S20.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\CarolM\Dropbox\MC_Classes\SPRING 2020\MATH 490 - CPX VAR\HOMEWORK\HW3

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

TeXworks can output a PDF even though WinEdt can't.

I have used the WinEdt combo with MiKTeX for about 15 years? More? I'm desperate to use WinEdt.  I need the menus.

Comment: Please provide small complete document (with dummy text) which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Don't use texify if you get errors. Run the tools one by one. The error says that the format is wrong. Try to regenerate it in the miktex console, settings->format tab